# External API's Calling My API Secured with Azure Active Directory

Tags: oauth, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

If I have an API secured with Azure Active Directory, what is the flow when an external API wants to talk to my internal API?

Is this just an API to API call as normal or is this a special circumstance and needs handling a different way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Is this just an API to API call as normal or is this a special circumstance and needs handling a different way?**

**The special circumstance** may depend on the confidentiality of the resources served by these api(s) and the level of security your application needs. In the end it is an api to api call only.

There are two approaches you can use if Azure Active Directory (AAD) is your Identity Provider for the entire application.

Application Identity with OAuth 2.0 client credentials grant provided by AAD. The calling API makes a request to AAD token endpoint with its client id, client secret (credential) and the application id (the unique id for the callee API) to receive an access token as response. This token is used as Bearer token to call the downstream API. In this approach client id, client secret, application id that are exchanged for an access token, are static values. Some one who has access to these values may find a way to compromise application security (highly unlikely).

The second approach is Delegated User Identity with OAuth 2.0. A request is made to AAD token endpoint with client id, client secret, the access token received as part of calling the tier1 API and a special on_behalf_of parameter to receive an access token, refresh token as response. We preferred this approach as it uses a dynamic value (access token from tier1 api) and also provides a refresh token.

You can read more about these approaches [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-scenarios/)

If you do not want to use AAD, you can use asp.net built in OwinAuthenticationMiddleware to generate and validate your own access tokens. As said earlier it all depends on your application requirements and implementation details, but in the end it is an API to API call.

Hopefully this is helpful, please let me know if you have any questions.

Thank you,
Soma.

Answer (score 0):

[oAuth](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/OAuth) is done for loggin **user** to a webservice [(see also reference here)](http://oauth.net/).

> Use OAuth to give your users access to their data while protecting their account credentials.

As another webservice wants to consume one of your service best way to do so is to have another authentication method in order to authorize

Other API, I assume you are talking of machines and not users (alias humans).
So best way is to provide **another auth mechanism** in order to authorize machines to connect to your API in a safe way. 
A simple way to do a machine connection is using a private [PKI](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Public_key_infrastructure) with public/private key. 
A good reference for PKI : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/certpath/CertPathProgGuide.html